# Fortify scan issue for (XSS) Cross-Site Scripting: DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, fortify

I am getting critical **Fortify** scan issue for (XSS) Cross-Site Scripting: DOM.
Following is my code. *data* is the html I have to display the HTML content returned as is. 
How can I fix this?

```
    $.get("somelink.html",
            {
                id : id,
            },
            function(data)
                {
                   $("#elementid").html(data);
                }
```

I can not encode *data* as I need to show the returned content as is in the div.
Please let me know if I am missing something obvious here.

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
< table> 
<tr><td>Number:</td><td>13256467</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Certificate:</td><td><a href="…">LINK</a></td></tr> 
<tr> <td>Attachments:</td> <td> </td> </tr>
< /table>
```

Comment: Do you trust `somelink.html` (e.g. it’s the same origin as the running page and you don’t have any unusual web security model)? If so, it’s a false positive. If not, you need to sanitize the HTML before displaying it (which is not particularly easy).

Comment: @Ry- When you say false positive do i just need to communicate that with justification and the report or we can make fortify ignore this in future scans?

Comment: I don’t know how Fortify specifically works, sorry. Definitely don’t turn off the rule responsible for reporting it, though.

Comment: did you try using https:// instead of http://  ?  also try to use $.ajax instead of $.get as it is more customisable.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, $("#elementid").innerHTML = data; works fine but on latest fortify scan update, it is still complaining.
Only solution i see, using .textContent which passes the test but we loose on the HTML when showing response.